# How to intercept a file transfer communication and send a different file?

Tags: security, networking, digital-signature, file-transfer

This is an interview question I couldn't solve:

You have a client and a server. The client can send a file to the server, and the server executes the file. Here is the communication protocol:

1. The client sends a `HELLO` command to the server
2. The server sends a challenge to the client
3. The client sends the file, a hash of the file, the challenge, and a hash of the challenge.
4. The server verifies that the challenge and the file match to their hash sent by the client, and sends OK/Error whether the verification succeed.

[image]

A third party can intercept the communication and change the message. Your job, as a third party, is **to intercept the communication and send a different file**, but you don't know the hash algorithm.

What are some possible solutions here?

What I thought about is to try and learn the hash algorithm, but they said it's too complex and there's a simpler way.

Comment: Should this be done after the one single connection attempt?

Comment: You can use as many connections as you want and it can be done in any one of them

Comment: @AlonGubkin well, if you can capture two connections at the same time, then you send the fake file as the challenge in one connect and the real challenge in the second connect. Then you have the hash of both file and one of challenges. That's what you need for successful attack over one connection. Second connection will have to be interrupted in some way.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp why is this a comment? add it as an answer!

Comment: Ok, I'll move it together with some additions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can capture two connections (either at the same time or consecutive ones), then you act as follows:

- during first connection MITM sends its fake file as a challenge to the client. The client returns the hash of the fake file. Now the connection must be interrupted to avoid the unnecessary entries in the log of the server or the client (which would happen if you let the procedure continue).
- As we have interrupted first connection, the client will re-connect. On this stage MITM lets the client get the real challenge and send the new challenge, its hash and the client's file and its hash to MITM. MITM replaces the file and its hash with the fake file and the fake hash, obtained during the first attempt and sends everything to the server.

This scheme requires that (a) the client can handle large file as a challenge (ie. it doesn't have a fixed-sized buffer or length checks), (b) the client will re-connect if the first connection is dropped, and (c) we can let entries about dropped connection get into server's or client's logs.

Requirement "a" seems to be quite serious and in real-world environments validity checks for input parameters (such as challenge) are mandatory.